# How to rename a field in PyQGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I have a layer with one field and I would like to rename that field with PyQGIS.

I guess it can be done using the QGIS tool "refactorfields" but I don't know how to use it in PyQGIS...

My other idea was to create a new field and next copy the values from field1 to the new field and than delete field1.

That is the code I came up with the help of the docs:

```
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("Field_xy", QVariant.String)])

    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        id = feature.attributes()
        feature.setAttribute('Field_xy', id[0])
        channel2.updateFeature(feature)

    layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([0])
```

unfortunately, I get the following error message:

> KeyError: Field_xy

It refers to the `feature.setAttribute()` line. I guess it means that the field 'Field_xy' doesn't exist. But I've created the field in the line above the for loop haven't I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the function 
`QgsVectorLayer.renameAttribute(index, newName)` documentation is [here](https://qgis.org/api/3.10/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ad45989d6c5547499fe9ab95e75240579).

And here is a minimal code example to change an attribute from `old_name` to `new_name`:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
idx_to_change = lyr.fields().names().index(old_name)
lyr.startEditing()
lyr.renameAttribute(idx_to_change , new_name)
lyr.updateFields()
lyr.commitChanges()
```

Comment: wow perfect, that works much better than every idea I came up with. Thanks!!